# Background fixed not centered when there is a scrollbar

Tags: css, background, scrollbar, center, fixed

I've got a problem with the background of my container. 
When there is a scrollbar, there is a gap between my content and my background. There isn't any problem when there is no scrollbar.

[capture](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=632205prob.jpg)

I think that's because my background is centered on the whole window (scrollbar include) and my content is centered by the margin: 0 auto; (that doesn't include the scrollbar).

Here is my css code...

```
#container{
    background-image:url('../img/container.png');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    padding:0 37px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    }
```

I've tried to add a padding left of 15px, it works but when there's no scrollbar, that's not centered anymore! 
When my background is not fixed, it works too but I need to keep it fixed...

Do you have a solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Could you not create your background box in HTML/CSS instead? That would ensure that the positioning is all consistent.

Comment: You mean put the image directly in the html, and not in the css?

I've just tried. First i thinked it worked but that's the same problem... Maybe i'm doing it wrong...

Comment: If your image is part of your HTML is should be perfectly centered along with your DIV...

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
background-position:top center;
```

> The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical.

[CSS background-position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Correct the code using

```
background-position:center top;
```